# How can I do multiple window.onscrolls

Tags: javascript, html

What happens is the rocketship turns round and the background does some stuff when the user scrolls down 50px. How can I make it so that the rocket does something else when the user scrolls down 100px?

here is my code

```
<script>
      window.onscroll = function() {

        var scrollamount = document.body.scrollTop;
        var otherscrollamount = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
        var rocket = document.getElementById("rocketship");
        var backgroundone = document.getElementById("one");
        var backgroundtwo = document.getElementById("two");

        if (scrollamount > 50 || otherscrollamount > 50) {
          rocket.setAttribute("style", "transform: rotate(90deg); animation: turn1 1s;");
          backgroundone.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 0; animation: fade2 1s;");
        }

        else if (scrollamount < 50 || otherscrollamount < 50) {
          rocket.setAttribute("style", "transform: rotate(0deg); animation: turn2 1s;");
          backgroundone.setAttribute("style", "opacity: 1; animation: fade1 1s;");
        }

        else if (scrollamount < 100 || otherscrollamount < 100) {
          // other stuff
        }

        else if (scrollamount > 100 || otherscrollamount > 100) {
          //other stuff
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to test your conditions to see that their order is wrong:

```
    if (scrollamount > 50 || otherscrollamount > 50) {
        // This wil execute even if scroll value is greater than 100
        // Last condition will never be evaluated
    }
    else if (scrollamount < 50 || otherscrollamount < 50) {
        // This will execute only if the first condition returned false and scroll value != 50
    }
    else if (scrollamount < 100 || otherscrollamount < 100) {
      // This will execute only if scroll value == 50
    }
    else if (scrollamount > 100 || otherscrollamount > 100) {
      // This won't execute, because previous conditions covered all possible values
    }
```

Rearrange your conditions like this:

```
// If you need greater scroll, add condition above this one
// Evaluate first greater than
if (scrollamount > 100 || otherscrollamount > 100) {

}
else if (scrollamount > 50 || otherscrollamount > 50) {
    // Below condition not needed, scroll value is between 51 and 100
    // if (scrollamount < 100 || otherscrollamount < 100)
}
else {
    // Below condition not needed, unless you want to omit action if scroll == 50
    // if (scrollamount < 50 || otherscrollamount < 50)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not very clear which exact conditions you want to check for but I think you want to do it like this:

```
if (scrollamount > 100 || otherscrollamount > 100) {
  // Scrolled > 100
} else if (scrollamount > 50 || otherscrollamount > 50) {
  // Scrolled 51-100
} else {
  // Scrolled 1-50
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set ranges of values by saying `scrollAmount >= 50 && scrollAmount < 100` to maximize the control over when what should happen. This way you can create a start and a stop value of when do something.

The `document.body` element doesn't always change. Instead check for either the `document.scrollingElement.scrollTop` value or, as you already do, the `document.documentElement.scrollTop` as fallback.

Place your element selectors outside of the `onscroll` function, as these elements only have to be selected once. This will same some performance.

Change the `className` property values on the elements to set a class instead of setting inline styles. Though setting inline styles is not wrong, it can certainly help to keep your CSS and JavaScript separated if you'll need to edit the styles or scripts.

```js
var rocket = document.getElementById("rocketship");
var backgroundone = document.getElementById("one");
var backgroundtwo = document.getElementById("two");

window.onscroll = function() {

  var scrollamount = document.scrollingElement.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

  if (scrollAmount < 50) {
    rocket.className = 'rocket-stage-1';
    backgroundone.className = 'background-stage-1';
  } else if (scrollamount >= 50 && scrollamount < 100) {
    rocket.className = 'rocket-stage-2';
    backgroundone.className = 'background-stage-2';
  } else if (scrollamount >= 100 && scrollamount < 150) {
    // other stuff
  }

}
```

```css
.rocket-stage-1 {
  transform: rotate(0deg); 
  animation: turn2 1s;
}

.background-stage-1 {
  opacity: 1; 
  animation: fade1 1s;
}

.rocket-stage-2 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  animation: animation: turn1 1s;
}

.background-stage-2 {
  opacity: 0; 
  animation: fade2 1s;
}
```